# How to set selected item from selectonemenu before commandbutton action executed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I have a Commandbutton and a Selectonemenu. I want to set selectedTaxType before Commandbutton action method is executed. I changed "action" to "oncomplete" but this time it freezes.Any solution?

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit"
   action="Controller.addSelectionToDatabase"                                 
   update="table"                                 
   immediate="true"
/>

<p:selectOneMenu id="selectTaxTypeId" value="#{Controller.selectedTaxType}" converter="taxTypeCodeSelectItemsConverter">                           
                <f:selectItems value="#{Controller.taxTypeList}" var="taxType"
                               itemLabel="#{taxType.shortName}"
                               itemValue="#{taxType}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: You remove immediate="true" and set process="selectTaxTypeId" in <p:commandButton.

Comment: "set selectedTaxType before Commandbutton action method is executed", with jsf, it's alway true.

Comment: @RongNK I removed immediate="true" and set process="selectTaxTypeId" and nothing happens when i click to button now.

Comment: action="#{Controller.addSelectionToDatabase}" not action="Controller.addSelectionToDatabase".

Comment: if it doesn't work, you need to provive code: converter and bean.

Answer (score 0):

Add an ajax event on valueChange which updates what you want.

example:

```
   <p:selectOneMenu id="selectTaxTypeId" value="#{Controller.selectedTaxType}" converter="taxTypeCodeSelectItemsConverter">                           
                    <f:selectItems value="#{Controller.taxTypeList}" var="taxType"
                                   itemLabel="#{taxType.shortName}"
                                   itemValue="#{taxType}" />
                    <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="@form" />
   </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: `valueChange` is not a valid event for `<p:selectOneMenu/>`, you want `change` instead. `update="@form"` is also unnecessary. You also need to advise OP that all this will fail if the backing bean is not in the `@ViewScope`